# Rails Bootstrap glyphicons

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

So I have been having a lot of issues with getting `bootstraps glyphicons` working. I have finally been able to get them to show on site. The only problem that I am now having, is I get the following errors in my DOM:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2                      jquery.self-660adc5….js?body=1:3734
GET http://localhost:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff                       localhost/:1
GET http://localhost:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf 404 (Not Found)        localhost/:1
```

Just so everyone is aware, when I select `jquery.self-660adc5...js?body=1:3734` I get taken to the following line of code: `support.inlineBlockNeedsLayout = val = div.offsetWidth === 3;`

In my terminal I get the following:

```
Started GET "/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2" for ::1 at 2016-04-18 21:57:17 -0600

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2")
```

I currently have all bootstrap glyphicon files in `vendor/assets/fonts/`

```
glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot   glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg   glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
```

In my `application.css` folder I have:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url('../assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
    src: url('../assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

In `application.rb`

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails}/vendor/assets/fonts"
config.assets.precompile += %w(.svg .eot .woff .ttf .woff2)
```

In `mime_types.rb`

```
Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES['.woff'] = 'application/x-font-woff'
```

I guess where I am confused is that the `glyphicons` are showing up and working, however, I am still getting the error in the DOM as well as in my terminal that these files cannot be found. Any suggestions on how I can handle this? I initially had the `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.0'` installed but ultimately just dl'd the bootstrap package and added it to my project.

Unfortunately I have yet to resolve this issue. For now I have included the Bootstrap CDN keys:

```
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This obviously removes the errors for now. If anyone else has any solution or needs more information on how to solve this issue please do comment. I will be most eager to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

You still need to add `woff2` files to the asset pipeline:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(.svg .eot .woff .woff2 .ttf)
```

Comment: Whoops, forgot to add that. I have now done so but still getting the errors involving `woff2, woff, ttf`.

Comment: Have you double-checked that all 5 of the font files you listed are present in `vendor/assets/fonts`?

Comment: Yes, all five files are there. Here is my repo in case you want to take a look: https://github.com/Nappstir/my_family

Comment: Any idea as to why these errors in my DOM would still be occurring?

Comment: Are you setting the appropriate Rails environment when precompiling?  e.g., `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: I am. I just have no idea why I'm getting these errors.